# how do I run concurrent background process from shell script?

Tags: bash

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read device; do
        name=$(echo "$device" | awk '{ print $1 }')
        ip=$(echo "$device" | awk '{ print $2 }')
        while read creds; do
                community=$(echo "$creds" | awk '{ print $1 }')
                version=$(echo "$creds" | awk '{ print $2 }')
                mkdir -p walks/$name;
                `echo -e "snmpwalk -v$version -c \x27$community\x27 $ip system > walks/$name/$community-$version.txt
        done < <(##MySQL query that returns tuples in form: (snmp_ro,(1,2c,3))##")
done < <(cat devices.txt)
exit 0
```

This is meant to go through and find the snmp string and version of each device.

devices.txt is a list of devices in form: hostname  ip

It doesn't create the file: walks/$name/$community-$version.txt, and it only seems to run through the walks 1 at a time, something I don't want.

Comment: `< <(cat devices.txt)`? Why not `< devices.txt`?

Comment: Please run your code through http://shellcheck.net first.

Comment: And the backticks around the `echo` command is just broken; that's not how you background a process in bash.

Comment: @chepner, check spelling; I assume you mean http://shellcheck.net/ :)

Comment: Also, `read creds` is silly when you're just going to split the contents with awk. Why not `read community version _`, and get rid of the awk?

Comment: I quoted it wrong, thats why the last backtick is missing

Comment: Background complex tasks in subshells, e.g. `while read; do (: &); done < infile`. You can see this works with a simpler example like `for x in {1..10}; do (sleep 10 &); done`, even though the subshell isn't really necessary for the example.

Comment: BTW, to understand a little more of why this didn't work (with the redirection inside of an `echo`), see BashFAQ #50 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050. (In short: Interpreting the output of an expansion, such as your backticks, doesn't go through full shell parsing, but only string-splitting and glob expansion; quotes aren't honored, and neither are redirections).

Comment: @CodeGnome, I'd argue that the subshell is not only unnecessary but best avoided unless one has a specific need: Not just overhead, but it breaks `$!`, means that job control won't track the process even if enabled, and mucks things up a bit re: the parent/child relationship (making the process an inherited child rather than a direct one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` to put the contents you want backgrounded in, well, the background.

```
pids=( )
while read -r -u 3 name ip _; do
  while read -r -u 4 community version _; do
    mkdir -p "walks/$name"
    snmpwalk -v"$version" -c "$community" "$ip" system \
      </dev/null >"walks/$name/$community-$version.txt" & pids+=( "$!" )
  done 4< <(: get data for "$name" and "$ip")
done 3<devices.txt
wait "${pids[@]}"
```

Other items of note:

- `read` can already split fields into their own variables; using `awk` for this is silly.
- The `_` in `read -r foo bar _` ensures that if more than two columns exist in the input file, the third column and onward are discarded (actually, put into a variable named `_`, but this is considered discard by convention) rather than appended to `bar`.
- Make a habit of quoting expansions unless you have a specific and compelling reason to do otherwise; otherwise, you get string-splitting and glob expansion of string contents.
- This example puts each input stream on its own file descriptor, and redirects each `read` to its own FD. This prevents any other content within your loop from consuming stdin.

Comment: I would add nohup to it as well for completeness.  The background task will terminate with the shell otherwise.

Comment: @ojblass, I'd only go there if the OP explicitly wants that behavior. Often, it's better to track a list of PIDs and wait for them, so the shell script *doesn't* exit until its children are done. (This also allows better error reporting).

Comment: @ojblass, also, even if that's what you want, `nohup` isn't the best way to get there. See the shell builtin `disown`, particularly including its option `-h`. (Note, too, that `huponexit` is an *option*, not constantly enabled, on-by-default behavior).

Comment: @ojblass, ...I've extended the example here to show the explicit tracking approach, albeit not the fancier version (tracking a relationship between the PIDs and their individual output files to allow the output files to be deleted if the command generating their content failed).

Comment: @ojblass, ...also, it's not accurate that a script exiting will kill all background processes it spawned. A *terminal* exiting will do that, for processes which have stdin, stdout or stderr connected to it, but that can be resolved simply by redirecting the relevant FDs -- which is most of what `nohup` does (the remainder being suppressing HUP-on-exit behavior, but that's off by default in bash anyhow).